# key hash.encoding in crypto.json required

Tags: beta, vapor

I just recently updated to Vapor 2.0 beta and I'm receiving this error at run time. What is causing this?

```
fatal error: Error raised at top level: Configuration error: Key `hash.encoding` in `Config/crypto.json` of type String required.: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-802.0.48/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 188
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose an encoding for your hashes.

https://github.com/vapor/api-template/blob/beta/Config/crypto.json#L3
http://beta.docs.vapor.codes/vapor/hash/#encoding